# VMware vCenter Server Standard and Foundation Editions

Tags: vmware-vcenter

Wondering whether anyone could advise as to the differences between these two products, from my understanding the difference is the latter allows control of more than 3 hosts. What I really wanted to know was, the (cool) features like chargeback and extended Application monitoring are they included in both versions or am I missing something....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation has all of the features of regular VC but is limited to 3 host, that's all.

Chargeback and AppSpeed are separate products that are chargable whichever VC version you have.

Answer (score 1):

VMware vCenter Server Standard includes the following additional features:

- VMware vCenter Orchestrator, an IT process automation engine that gives administrators the tools they need to better automate the environment.
- VMware vCenter Server Linked Mode that enables a common inventory view across multiple instances of VMware vCenter Server.

Answer (score 1):

vSphere 6.5 Update 1 supports up to 4 ESX Hosts in vCenter Server Foundation:
see http://www.virten.net/2017/07/whats-inside-vmware-vsphere-6-5-update-1/

Marc

Comment: if that link goes away, so does the answer. Summarizing, in your own words, the content found in that blog post in your answer, would likely lead to an accepted answer.